# Time format conversion from numerical to clock

Tags: r, datetime, time, datetime-format, time-format

I want to convert the column containing times, for example, to convert 13.5 PM into clock time format i.e. 13:30 PM. Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another approach

```
vec <- c("13.5 PM", "12.2 AM")


library( magrittr )  
as.POSIXct( gsub( " .M", "", vec) %>% 
              as.numeric() * 3600,  
            origin = "01-01-1970", 
            tz = "UTC" ) %>% 
  format( "%H:%M" )

[1] "13:30" "12:12"
```

You can use %p for AM/PM (with %I for the hours, if your locale supports it), but this seems redundant, since your time is in 24h format.

without pipes:

```
format( as.POSIXct( as.numeric( gsub( " .M", "", vec) ) * 3600, origin = "01-01-1970", tz = "UTC" ), "%H:%M" )

#[1] "13:30" "12:12"
```

Comment: very good! works also with the data of Julius. `library(magrittr)` though!

Comment: thanks @AndreElrico, updated...

Comment: Thank you very much it worked

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty general approach with rounding:

```
x <- c("13.5 PM", "9.003 AM", "23.823 PM", "5.1234 AM")

library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("((?<=.)\\d+(?= ))", function(x, ...)
  sprintf("%02d", round(as.numeric(paste0("0.", x)) * 60)), x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "13.30 PM" "9.00 AM"  "23.49 PM" "5.07 AM"
```

Comment: very good that's much more general than mine. Don't like the dependency to a 3rd party package though.

Comment: Thank you very much it is working as you did. But i have a column having these values and when I use the modified command I get error. Can you guide me about this? the code I used was gsubfn("((?<=.)\\d+(?= ))", function(data$STime, ...)
  sprintf("%02d", round(as.numeric(paste0("0.", data$STime)) * 60)), data$STime, perl = TRUE)

the error I got is  Error: unexpected ',' in "  sprintf("%02d", round(as.numeric(paste0("0.", data$STime)) * 60)),"

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal, try gsubfn("((?<=.)\\d+(?= ))", function(x, ...)
  sprintf("%02d", round(as.numeric(paste0("0.", x)) * 60)), data$STime, perl = TRUE). The second argument is simply a function definition, so `x` there shouldn't change.  It is the penultimate argument where you need to specify the vector of times that should be modified.

Comment: it gave an error but it has been solved using the magrittr library thank you for looking into the problem

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal, most likely your column is a factor. In that case you need to as `as.character` as in library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("((?<=.)\\d+(?= ))", function(x, ...)
    sprintf("%02d", round(as.numeric(paste0("0.", x)) * 60)), as.character(df$a), perl = TRUE)